# Restrict access to edit some content types on a list Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

I know you can´t set permissions on a content type level but here is what i want to acomplish, maybe someone can help me out (i don´t have Designer, admin access or code knowledge). 
I have a list with several content types, every content type is a like a "stage" of an incident and different group of people are in charge on capturing data in every content type, is there any way that i can allow these groups to edit only a specific content type?

For example...

user 1 adds customer name... issue description... saves the item and assigns it to user 2.

user 2 opens the item and edits only specific fields and assigns the items to the next stage or user 3 but if there is something wrong with the data user 2 will assign it back to user 1.

Every user has to be able to view the data but only edit certain content types.

Is it possible? without deep tech knowledge?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you do not need deep technical knowledge to solve this issue.

Creating a new list forms and hiding the fields depending on each user group will solve this issue along with a custom workflow.

Find out the tutorial on how to create new list form using the following youtube URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpbxEnMCWgw

For Custom approval workflow tutorial please check the following on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cvrf_rf9wMs